# Simple regular expression pattern for php

Tags: php, regex

How to write a regular expression that will pass a numbers from 60 to 99?

Comment: So, what have you tried? Did you read any regular expression documentation?

Comment: Just pick the 2-figures number and check if it's between 60 and 99

Comment: what's wrong with `if ($i > 60 && $i < 99)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[6-9][0-9]`

Answer (score 7):

Fairly straightforward:

```
/^[6-9][0-9]$/
```

But why are you using regex for this?

Answer (score 3):

Regular expressions is a poor tool for such task. You should really drop to a numerical comparison.

But since you ask, here's how:

```
/^[6-9][0-9]$/
```

Related questions:

- [How to generate a regular expression at runtime to match a numeric range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6349161/how-to-generate-a-regular-expression-at-runtime-to-match-a-numeric-range)
- [Regular Expression: Numeric range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377926/regular-expression-numeric-range)
- [number range in a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031655/number-range-in-a-regex)

Answer (score 3):

I would probably do it by checking via `($n >= 60 && $n <= 99)`, but a possible regex is:

```
/^[6-9][0-9]$/
```

Answer (score 1):

could also use an if case:

```
if($value >= 60 && $value <= 99) { // do stuff}
```